# Splitting csv-file with awk on column

Tags: csv, awk, sh

I have a big csv-file that I want to split in smaller csv-file, I have a somewhat working solution:

```
awk -F\t '{print > $2}'  big.csv
```

But my problem is that I want the files to have .csv at the end, not just the column as it is now. Any ideas?

big.csv

```
"a name" "type" "some more info" "and a bit more"
"a other name" "differnt-type" "more" "and a bit more"
"last name" "type" "something" "and last more"
```

the result I want:

type.csv

```
"a name" "type" "some more info" "and a bit more"
"last name" "type" "something" "and last more"
```

different-type.csv

```
"a other name" "differnt-type" "more" "and a bit more"
```

as it is now the files will be type & different-type without .csv.

I have also looked at a solution like this:

```
tail -n +1 big.csv | while IFS=$'\t' read d1 d2 c
do
 echo $d1'\t'$d2'\t'$c >> ${d2}.csv
done
```

Which works but is painfully slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
awk -F'\t' '{fname=$2".csv"; print > fname; close(fname)}' big.csv
```

`awk` will keep the output files open until you call `close()` or `awk` exits. Explicitly calling `close(fname)` makes sure that you won't run out of file descriptors even if there are many different values of `$2` (which would lead to many open files)

Note: You need to enclose the `\t` in quotes like: `-F'\t'`.

Comment: Will `-F\t` work? Shouldn't it be rather `-F'\t'`? :)

Comment: Right, was missing that. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I skipped the close(fname) since I know how many files it will be and don't need to close because it won't be over 15-20, if I didn't, it would need >> instead of > to not only get the last row when it types over itself every time it opens the file. :)

Comment: Can be that I was wrong. It should work without quotes actually. Let me get back to you later.

Comment: @hek2mgl I think that would be strange, wouldn't it? `bash` removes the backslash, passing only `-Ft` which would make `t` the delimiter. Simple test: `awk -F\t '{print $2}' <<< $'1\t2\t3'`.

Comment: True! @Elmseld Not sure how `-F\t` could work for you. Probably you are calling this from another program (which interpretes the `\t` before calling the shell command?)

Comment: @PesaThe with that test I get the result, 2.

Comment: @hek2mgl I don't know why it works but I have tried it in iTerm, terminal and as a script-file and it works fine. But I will add the ' ' anyway to prevent future problems.